# android views are cut on RTL

Tags: android, imageview

I'm making an app that will also be available in RTL interface (Hebrew, Arabic, etc.)
The problem is that on the RTL interface, some views get cut and doesn't show the full content.
The cut `ImageView` code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/account"
    android:contentDescription="@string/profilePic"
    android:id="@+id/profilePic" />
```

It gets cut on the left side when it shows in RTL interface and fully shown in the LTR interface.
When I try to set the width to `match_parent` it doesn't cut the photo, but that's not what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I figured out how to solve my problem.
The `ImageView` is placed in a `RelativeLayout` that is set to `wrap_content` in both height and width.
I added a small View (technically, I think you can use any view you'd like to, I used an `ImageButton`), set `layout:align` on both `Right`, `Bottom` and `End` to `@+id/profilePic` and set it's visibility to `INVISIBLE`.

Comment: This didn't solved the problem for me